# Bootstrap 5 second toast not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Hello guys i have problem with second toast which is not displaying.

HTML:

```
<div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
<!-- FIRST -->
  <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
    <i class="fas fa-duck"></i>
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      See? Just like this.
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- SECOND -->
  <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
    <i class="fas fa-duck"></i>
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      See? Just like this.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Script looks like

```
        <script>
window.onload = (event)=> {
 let myAlert = document.querySelector('.toast');
 let bsAlert = new  bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);
 bsAlert.show();
}
                </script>
```

My question is how can i fix it to display second toast on my site

Answer (score 1):

`show()` only works for one element , you have to make a loop for all your toasts if you want to show them in one event:

```
$.each($('.toast'),function(i,item){ new bootstrap.Toast(item).show();});
```

Comment: @Yah Ya It works, but when i click "close" on the selected one, two toasts are closing

Answer (score 0):

I just created a class named `start-toast` for all of the messages that will be displayed when the page is ready, and then applied the `toast()` method with the parameter `'show'`, to all of the messages with that custom class  . According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/), you should be able to also stack them up with the `toast-container` class.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".start-toast").toast('show');
            });
```

```html
       
        <!-- JQuery - to handle with with the DOM easier !-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 " style="z-index: 11">
            <div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" class="toast hide start-toast" id="welcomeToast" role="alert">
                <div class="toast-header">
                    <strong></strong>
                    <strong class="me-auto">Welcome!!</strong>
                    <small>0 min ago</small>
                    <button aria-label="Close" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body">
                    How are you doing ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```